# Pointer variables changes same time in C?

Tags: c

This is a function that returns the current directory:

```
char* xyz(){
    static TCHAR* Buffer[BUFSIZE];

    GetCurrentDirectory(BUFSIZE, Buffer);
   // _tprintf(TEXT(" %s\n"), Buffer);
    return Buffer;

}


char *currentvar=xyz();
char *currentvarmake=xyz();
```

And I assign this function to these 2 variable. But when I change something on `currentvar` it effects `currentvarmake` and they both change. I don't want them. I only want to change one of them. I want them to be independent.

Comment: Make a `xyz_str` function that takes caller-provided buffer space to populate. Of course, that makes the very point of this function rather meaningless; may as well just have the caller invoke `GetCurrentDirectory` and leave it at that.

Comment: You seem to be missing a fundamental piece of understanding about how pointers work.

Comment: @WhozCraig That's pointless in this case, as `xyz` would then just be a pure wrapper around `GetCurrentDirectory`, which already works that way.

Comment: That was the point of my finishing sentence, but thanks for the affirmation.

Comment: That wasn't there when I wrote my comment.

Comment: Maybe you want `malloc`?

Comment: are you sure it is `static TCHAR* Buffer[BUFSIZE];` rather than `static char Buffer[BUFSIZE];`  ? else not compatible with the return type being `char *` and not `TCHAR**` . Out of that you return always the same array

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to make a wrapper to replace `char *currentvar=malloc(BUFSIZE); GetCurrentDirectory(BUFSIZE, currentvar);`?

Comment: static char Buffer[BUFSIZE];  When ı do that and debug it .ıt says cannot accsess memort at adress .(I understand that ı am always returnin same array) . how can ı change it ?

Comment: @SevalMercan P__J__ answer proposes one solution, and I propose two, it is as you want ^^

Answer (score 2):

1. Use correct types as per documentation
2. You need to allocate the memory every time to get distinct strings.

```
LPTSTR xyz(void)
{
    LPTSTR Buffer = malloc(BUFSIZE *sizeof(*LPTSTR));
    if(Buffer)
    {
         GetCurrentDirectory(BUFSIZE, Buffer);
    }
    return Buffer;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `free` when you are finished using the strings

Comment: I do not have to. OP has to

Answer (score 2):

First you do not wanted

> ```
> static TCHAR* Buffer[BUFSIZE];
> ```

but

```
static TCHAR Buffer[BUFSIZE];
```

to be compatible with `GetCurrentDirectory`

Note also a TCHAR is not necessary a `char`, you take a risk using `TCHAR`then `char`

Second because *Buffer* is `static` you always return the same pointer, then each call to the function modify the value you return the previous time(s), and if you modify that value by yourself that also modify the other time(s) still using the return pointer.

To avoid that you need to deeply copy the result, you can do that in your function or outside.

- If you do in the function using `malloc` or `strcpy` (if simple char) for instance, the caller has to know it receives a dynamically allocated array to it will have to free it when it will become useless, else you will have memory leaks.
- If you do that outside the caller has to copy or duplicate the result if needed.

Both solutions are good and at the same time 'dangerous', if you look at the library functions some follow the first solution and some others the second.

Comment: static will not return separate `LPTSTR`ings

Comment: `will become useless` ?? probably `when not needed anymore`

Comment: @P__J__ is not the same 'useless' and 'not needed anymore' ???

Comment: static makes it non reentrant in the multitasking environment. definitely bad solution here

Comment: @P__J__ yes but this is what the OP did, and the OP never asked for a reentrant proposal,  and this is also the case for some libc functions, and you seem to forget I do not only propose the solution using *static*. So why so brutal, because you also answer ? Did you see me making remarks on your answer ?